# What is [numberformat] even useful for?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

Is there any *real* purpose for the tag [numberformat](/questions/tagged/numberformat)?  As far as I can see, it's simply a pithole for bad questions.

Comment: Isn't number formatting for questions regarding the way a number is printed, like 1,000 or 0.12 (rather than 0.1223253464787)

Comment: @RichardTingle well yes, but would anyone really search up that tag to answer questions about number formatting, and would the tag convey anything that isn't (or shouldn't) be in the title or the beginning part of the post?

Comment: There's also a number of methods in Java, PHP and other languages that use numberformat as it's name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[numberformat](/questions/tagged/numberformat) appears to be quite consistently being used for questions regarding the output formatting of numbers. For example `1,000`, `$20.05` or `0.12` (rather than `0.1223253464787`).

It has a clear meaning independent from other tags and so is not a "meta tag" and gives insight into what the question is likely to be about.